# Winforms using CefSharp crashes saying Accessviolation

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I have a WinForms application that would be running for hours. It started crashing after 3-4 hours intermittently. It uses CefSharp. Event logs shows error is something related to CEFSharp but I couldn't go any further..Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Machine: Windows 7 Sp1
VC++ runtime installed
.NET framework 4.7
The crash dump shows below information:
Exception: the thread tried to read from or write to a virtual 
address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Tried debugging crash dump, but not useful
```

Event logs below:

```
   - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   - <System>
     <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
     <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
     <Level>2</Level> 
       <Task>0</Task> 
     <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-31T14:38:54.000000000Z" /> 
     <EventRecordID>920</EventRecordID> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Security /> 
      </System>
    - <EventData>
      <Data>Application: Client.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
         Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled 
        exception. Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException at 
        CefSharp.Internals.MCefRefPtr<CefPostData>.op_Assign(CefPostData*) at 
        CefSharp.Internals.CefPostDataWrapper.~CefPostDataWrapper() at 
         CefSharp.Internals.CefPostDataWrapper.Dispose(Boolean) at 
               CefSharp.Internals.CefPostDataWrapper.Dispose() at 
              Client.AsmxRequestHandler+
```

ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback) {
            m_callback = callback;

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var postData = request.PostData)
                    {
                        if (postData.Elements != null)
                        {
                            var elements = postData.Elements;
                            var charSet = request.GetCharSet();
                            var element = elements[0];
                            var elementBodyString = string.Empty;
                            foreach (var elemt in elements)
                            {
                                if (element.Type == PostDataElementType.Bytes)
                                {
                                    elementBodyString += elemt.GetBody(charSet);
                                }
                            }

                            if (element.Type == PostDataElementType.Bytes)
                            {
                                XmlSerializer mySerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AsmxWrapperClasses.Envelope));

                                var mySoapRequest = (AsmxWrapperClasses.Envelope)mySerializerObj.Deserialize(GenerateStreamFromString(elementBodyString));
                                var requestBody = mySoapRequest.Body;

                                try
                                {
                                    var myResult = ProcessRequestBody(requestBody);

                                    var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(myResult);
                                    stream.Position = 0;
                                    ResponseLength = stream.Length;
                                    MimeType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(".asmx"));
                                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                                    Stream = stream;

                                    callback.Continue();
                                }
                                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                                {
                                    if (ex.Message == "requestBody invalid")
                                        throw new Exception(elementBodyString);
                                    throw;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    CLogger.GetInstance().LogError(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You're deep in bowels of CefSharp, using the [github site](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues) is the best way to get help with these kind of stability problems.

Comment: What version are you using? What does your request handler code look like?

Comment: What version are you using? What does your request handler code look like?

Comment: @amaitland Sorry for the late response, its CefSharp.WinForms" version="71.0.0" and cef.redist.x86 and x64 = 3.3578.1864.. request handler is general handler to process all kinds of request , nothing strange.. it uses  Task.Run(() =>..hope it answers?

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with version  73.1.130? I'll need to see the request handler code, please edit your question and add the source.

Comment: Added the request handler code..I will test with 73.1.130.. problem is reproducing a defect is very very intermittent.. sometimes it crash within 30 minutes , but most of time, it crashes after 6-7hours of running app.

Comment: Also may I know why specifically 73.1? is there some fix gone in related to app crashes?

Comment: Update today : we tested in another machine with same app which is using  cef version 65..it still crashes..Im yet to test with 73

Comment: @amaitland Can you see a problem with my answer? Is there a guideline anywhere  to dispose the incoming data?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I need an example that reproduces the problem before I can comment. The code above doesn't make sense to me, the stack trace says `RequestHandler` yet the method signature is for a `ResourceHandler`.

Comment: @amaitland I'll try to create a clean/simple example but I won't have time anytime soon. Even on my complex, real world app, it took a long time to reproduce. In any case, I would expect that the caller is responsible to manage the lifetime of the argument, the function probably shouldn't free any resources on its arguments. Unfortunately, I can't spend more time on this this week

Comment: In a lot of cases CefSharp will limit the lifetime of the unmanaged object wrapper to the scope of the function.  There are cases like OnBeforeResourceLoad where you can use the callback to continue at some later point, in this case the callback will dispose of the request upon execution. The request will free the post data.  If the callback isn't executed then we have to rely on the gc/finalizer.  I do recommend executing or disposing of the callback to ensure efficient memory management. Many improvements were made in version  75.

Comment: If you are experiencing the problem in version 75.1.142 then by all means open an issue on GitHub. You should be able to reliably dispose of the post data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
It looks like problem is that you dispose PostData

```
using (var postData = request.PostData)
```

The issue seems to be resolved if you remove that line.